# How to sort A - z in table view swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting

i have one table view, which will dipslay the json data from one url.Its all working fine. What i need is?. in my table view i have one lable called "name label ".Which will display the name in my table view.

And i have one menu option with one button name called" sort data A - z ".When i click that, my table view data should reload with sorting the date from A-z alphabets order ( My name title ).

This is my button action :

```
@IBAction func sortByAZBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    }
```

My **viewcontroller.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var RightMenu: UIView!



    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!   // UITable view declaration

    @IBOutlet weak var Resultcount: UILabel!     // count label

    var arrDict :NSMutableArray=[]   // array to store the value from json


    let cellSpacingHeight: CGFloat = 5  // cell spacing from each cell in table view


    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.jsonParsingFromURL()  // call the json method

        let nib = UINib(nibName:"customCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


        RightMenu.layer.borderWidth = 1



    }

    // web services method
    func jsonParsingFromURL () {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://sampleUrl.com”)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            // print("done, error: \(error)")

            if error == nil
            {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.arrDict=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSMutableArray

                    //print(self.arrDict)

                    if (self.arrDict.count>0)
                    {
                        self.Resultcount.text = "\(self.arrDict.count) Results"
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }}

                // arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("xxxx")
            }


        }
        dataTask.resume()


    }




    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.arrDict.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }





    // calling each cell based on tap and users ( premium / non premium )
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell:customCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell 


        cell.vendorName.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("name") as? String 
        cell.vendorAddress.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("address") as? String

        return cell 
    }


    // MARK:
    // MARK: Sort Method

    @IBAction func sortByRevBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.indicator.startAnimating()
         self.indicator.hidden = false
         RightMenu.hidden = true

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.indicator.stopAnimating()
            self.indicator.hidden = true


        };
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }


    @IBAction func sortByAZBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    }



}
```

Please help me out. I am not getting clear idea to do that...Thanks

Updated :

```
(
        {
        ad = 0;
        address = "900 York Mills Rd, Toronto, ON M3B 3H2, Canada";
        "category_id" = 1;

        latitude = "43.7563";
        longitude = "-79.3495";
        name = "Honeybee Restaurant";
        phone = 9876543210;
        rating = "5.0";
    },
        {
        ad = 1;
        address = "1677 Wilson Ave, Toronto, ON M3L 1A5, Canada";
        "category_id" = 1;

        latitude = "43.7194";
        longitude = "-79.5153";
        name = "Maki My Way";
        phone = 9875463254;
        rating = "4.0";
    },
        {
        ad = 1;
        address = "75 Bremner Blvd, Toronto, ON M5J 0A1, Canada";
        "category_id" = 1;

        latitude = "43.6429";
        longitude = "-79.3814";
        name = "Blow Fish Restaurant";
        phone = 9873245610;
        rating = "5.0";
    },
        {
        ad = 0;
        address = "4150 Yonge St, Toronto, ON M2P 2C6, Canada";
        "category_id" = 1;

        latitude = "43.747";
        longitude = "-79.4079";
        name = "SaigonFlower Restaurant";
        phone = 7892345621;
        rating = "3.0";
    },
        {
        ad = 1;
        address = "604 King St W, Toronto, ON M5V 1M6, Canada";
        "category_id" = 1;

        latitude = "43.6445";
        longitude = "-79.4004";
        name = "Sushi Gen";
        phone = 7456321065;
        rating = "2.0";
    },

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your array is an array of dictionaries and your dictionary has a "Name" key you can do this. Change the code if your dict has different keys that contains the name.

```
@IBAction func sortByAZBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) {
   arrDict.sortUsingComparator { (dict1, dict2) -> NSComparisonResult in
       if let name1 = dict1["name"] as? String, name2 = dict2["name"] as? String {
              return name1.compare(name2)
       }
       return .OrderedAscending
   }
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

For order by rating (High to low) you can use this.

```
arrDict.sortUsingComparator { (dict1, dict2) -> NSComparisonResult in
    if let name1 = dict1["rating"] as? String, name2 = dict2["rating"] as? String {
        return name2.compare(name1)
    }
    return .OrderedAscending
}
```

Comment: i am getting error that ` Value of type 'NSMutableArray' has no member 'sortInPlace' `

Comment: great !... works clearly. I have one more doubt. Like wise i have some json data name called "Rating", "Date of post".In my table view also rating , date of post date will be display. I also have sort by rating, sort by date. How can i do for that also.I also have 2 button action for sort by rating, sort by dateofpost...if you says that will be very help fulL.  i am struck with more than 2 hours. But you amazed !!!

Comment: i used same logic, but it doesn't work ` arrDict.sortUsingComparator { (dict1, dict2) -> NSComparisonResult in
            if let name1 = dict1["rating"] as? String, name2 = dict2["rating"] as? String {
                return name1.compare(name2)
            }
            return .OrderedAscending
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: i need to show the hight rating at first follwed by low rating...How can i return the value instead of . orderingAscending

Comment: i returned ` .orderedDecending` But still i showing from small number of rating to big number`..I need to show start from big number rating followed by small number

Comment: i jsut changed the string to float . and i am getting error that ` value of type 'float' has no member compare`

Comment: For descending according to rating use `return name2.compare(name1)` instead of the other way around.

Comment: yes, that i changes, But if i use float i am getting that error `value of type 'float' has no member compare`

Comment: i have change some code,So now sort is not working. Here is my post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332624/how-to-sort-the-table-view-from-a-z

Answer (score 1):

For sorting of the `tableview` you should sort youre `dataSource` firstly and than reload `tableview`.

In you're case:

Firstly sort by A to z:

> arrDict

For sorting use functional programming:

```
arrDict = arrDict.sort({ $0.name > $1.name })
```

Secondly reload tableview by:

> self.tableView.reloadData()

Comment: reload the tableview is fine, But i am not sure how to sort by data ??

Comment: You means my json data??

Comment: try sort and reload table view

Comment: i tried.But i am getting error that ` Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (Element, Element) -> Bool)' `

Answer (score 0):

sort `arrDict` using below code then `self.tableView.reloadData():`

```
sortedArray = [anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: `expected expression in container literal`..It alowing me to add extra commas