# How to sort the table view from A-z?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting

I am getting some data from one url and try to display in my table view In that I have three button name which is used to sort. Here is my `button action` method:

```
@IBAction func sortByAZBtnPress(sender: AnyObject) { }
@IBAction func sortByRatingBtnPress(sender: AnyObject){ }
@IBAction func sortByRecentBtnPress(sender: AnyObject){ }
```

And here is my `bussinesstype.swift` model class:

```
import UIKit

class BusinessData {

    var BusinessName: String?
    var Address: String?
    var Rating: Float?
    var ContactNumber: String?

    init(json: NSDictionary) {
        self.BusinessName = json["business_name"] as? String
        self.Address = json["location"] as? String
        self.Rating = json["__v"] as? Float
        self.ContactNumber = json["phone_no"] as? String
    }
}
```

Here is my `viewcontroller.swift`:

```
import UIKit    

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {        
    var isTapped:Bool?   // cell tap checking bool        
    var selectedIndex:NSIndexPath?        
    @IBOutlet weak var RightMenu: UIView!        
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!   // UITable view declaration       
    var arrDict = [BusinessData]()   // array to store the value from json

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.jsonParsingFromURL()  // call the json method

        // nib for custom cell (table view)
        let nib = UINib(nibName:"customCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")            
        indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90))
        indicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        indicator.center = self.view.center
        indicator.color = UIColor .redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(indicator)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "searchMethod:", name: "search", object: nil);
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "endSearch", name: "endSearch", object: nil);
    }

    // web services method
    func jsonParsingFromURL ()
    {
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://sample url/Fes?current_location=toronto&token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyIkX18")!            
        if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        {
            if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: [])) as? NSDictionary
            {
                if let reposArray = json["data"] as? [NSDictionary]
                {

                    for item in reposArray
                    {
                        let itemObj = item as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

                        let b_type = itemObj!["business_type"]?.valueForKey("type")                            

                        if (b_type as? String == "Taxis")
                        {                                
                            arrDict.append(BusinessData(json: item))                                
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }                    
    }

    // number of rows
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    // height for each cell
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return cellSpacingHeight
    }

    // calling each cell based on tap and users ( premium / non premium )
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell:customCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell            
         cell.vendorName.text = arrDict[indexPath.section].BusinessName
            cell.vendorAddress.text = arrDict[indexPath.section].Address
            cell.VendorRating.rating = arrDict[indexPath.section].Rating!

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: Sort Method

    @IBAction func sortByRevBtnPress(sender: AnyObject)
    {            
        self.indicator.startAnimating()
        self.indicator.hidden = false
        RightMenu.hidden = true

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (Int64)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue()){
            self.indicator.stopAnimating()
            self.indicator.hidden = true                
        };
        self.tableView.reloadData() 
    }        

    @IBAction func sortByAZBtnPress(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        RightMenu.hidden = true         
    }

    @IBAction func sortByRatingBtnPress(sender: AnyObject)
    {            
        RightMenu.hidden = true            
    }

    @IBAction func sortByRecentBtnPress(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        RightMenu.hidden = true        
    }
}
```

How can I sort the values in my table view `business_name`?

**Updated:**

```
BusinessData.sortUsingComparator { (dict1, dict2) -> NSComparisonResult in        
    if let name1 = dict1["business_name"] as? String, name2 = dict2["business_name"] as? String
    {
        return name1.compare(name2)
    }        
    return .OrderedAscending
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Sorting array using NSSortDescriptor is very simple, google it.

Comment: i already tried , please see my update.But its geting some error

Comment: Try `yourArr.sort { $0.Name < $1.Name }`, and why your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 1 all the time?

Comment: then what should i change my `numberOfRowsInSection` to??

Comment: As i understand in you table view now only one item but should be more, so  `numberOfRowsInSection` should `return youDataArr.coun`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort `var arrDict: [BusinessData]`:

**By business name**

A->Z:

```
arrDict.sort({ $0.BusinessName < $1.BusinessName })
```

Z->A:

```
arrDict.sort({ $0.BusinessName > $1.BusinessName })
```

**By rating**

```
arrDict.sort({ $0.Rating < $1.Rating })
```

By the way, by convention, variable names, such as `Rating` and `BusinessName` should be lowercase.